# How to show dates in csv file generated by Python

Tags: python, csv

I learned to scrape data from website by this video: [enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QhD015WUMxE)

My Python code is as follows:

```
#IMPORT LIBRARIES
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

#OPEN A NEW CSV FILE. IT CAN BE CALLED ANYTHING
file = open('csv_py.csv', 'w')

#CREATE A VARIABLE FOR WRITING TO THE CSV
writer = csv.writer(file)

#CREATE THE HEADER ROW OF THE CSV
writer.writerow(['Date', 'Content'])

#REQUEST WEBPAGE AND STORE IT AS A VARIABLE
page_to_scrape = requests.get("https://www.liechi.org/en/")
print(page_to_scrape)

#USE BEAUTIFULSOUP TO PARSE THE HTML AND STORE IT AS A VARIABLE
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_to_scrape.text, 'html.parser')

#FIND ALL THE ITEMS IN THE PAGE WITH A CLASS ATTRIBUTE OF 'archive-item-link'
#AND STORE THE LIST AS A VARIABLE
contents= soup.findAll('a', attrs={'class':'archive-item-link'})

#FIND ALL THE ITEMS IN THE PAGE WITH A CLASS ATTRIBUTE OF 'archive-item-date'

#AND STORE THE LIST AS A VARIABLE
dates = soup.findAll('span', attrs={'class':'archive-item-date'})

#LOOP THROUGH BOTH LISTS USING THE 'ZIP' FUNCTION
#AND PRINT AND FORMAT THE RESULTS
for date, content in zip(dates, contents):
    print(date.text+ "(" + content.text+ ")")

    #WRITE EACH ITEM AS A NEW ROW IN THE CSV
    writer.writerow([date.text, content.text])

#CLOSE THE CSV FILE
file.close()
```

The csv file is created, but I could not find the dates in the first column: after several checks, I found that I have to click the cell to let the date show up:
[image]

I wonder why we could not see the dates as the content in the csv file and how to fix it.
thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and include the first few lines of the resulting csv file as you copy and paste them **from a text editor** (not from a spreadsheet like Excel)?

Comment: "I found that I have to click the cell to let the date show up." -> perhaps the date is being retrieved by via javascript?

Comment: @mkrieger1:  I did as you suggest:) thanks!

Comment: You did precisely what I did *not* suggest... sorry if the bold part of my comment wasn't clear.

Comment: @snakecharmerb: I know nothing about javascript. sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I executed the code and noticed that you need to expand the cell length to see the date values.

One explanation is that `date.text` has new line characters and empty spaces in it.

For example one of the date.text values is

```
'\n        2017/02/26\n      '
```

You can clean this up by trimming all white space. Update your for loop with this:

```py
for date, content in zip(dates, contents):
    # trim white space fro date and content
    clean_date = date.text.strip()
    clean_content = content.text.strip()

    print(clean_date + "(" + clean_content+ ")")
    #WRITE EACH ITEM AS A NEW ROW IN THE CSV
    writer.writerow([clean_date, clean_content])
```

Comment: I wonder how I could accept your answer, you mean change the code in the question?

Comment: I wonder if you could help me with this question: what can I do if I only scrape the information of year 2017 instead of the whole website? the website is : `https://www.liechi.org/en/`